# Displaying data from database to input-group-addon

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to **display the data from the database** to these`input-group-addon` component from the bootstrap. These `input-group-addon` textboxes are disabled. I will only use these to display the data from the database. Then the user will just select their requests from here.[image: Front end]

[image: Database]

As you can see, the highlighted part (TrimmingIt is a trimming process) is one of the data from the database. It **should be inside** of the textbox. Here's my code. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Request Service|CRB</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media 
queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">
</script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>


<body>
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="trucks.php">Trucks</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="suppliers.php">Suppliers</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="clients.php">Clients</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="accountspayables.php">Uploaded Files</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="maintenance.php">Maintenance</a></li>
<!--  DROPDOWN start -->
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" 
aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  About us <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="contactus.php">Contact us</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="aboutus.php">About us</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<!-- END OF DROPDOWN -->
<li class="pull-right"><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-
user" aria-hidden="true"></a></li> 
</ul>
<!--  end of HEADER -->
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>

<div class="col-sm-8">

<h1  class="text-primary">Request Service</h1>
<?php
 //FETCH DATA FROM DB TO INPUT-GROUP-ADDON

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
function __construct($it) { 
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
}

function current() {
    return "<td>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() { 
  echo "<div class='input-group'>"; 
  echo "<span class='input-group-addon'>";
  echo " <input type='submit' aria-label='...' value='Request'>"; 
  echo "</span>"; 
  echo "<input type='text' disabled class='form-control' aria-label='...' 
value=' <?php echo '".$result['SERVICE_NAME']."'; ?>' >";
  echo "</div>"; 
} 

function endChildren() {                                                
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
} 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "crb";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
$password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_DESC FROM services"); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as 
$k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?> 

</div>

</div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as 
needed -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your php code ?

Comment: please scroll down

Comment: I'm sorry, excuse me. Where is the function beginChildren is called ?